# Get DataTables cell value to use in html link

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

I thought to be a simple thing, but!

Using DataTables, I would like to have the first column of the table hidden and use that cell data in an HTML image link in the next column cell.

html link using "User_ID",  http://somepage.php?UID=data0

I have looked at fnGetData() and mRender and I just confused now.

MY CODE:

```
"aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "User_ID",
                  "bVisible": false, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false
                },
                { "mData": null,
                  "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false,
                  "sClass": "center",
                  "sDefaultContent": '<a href="somepage.php?UID=' + "data from cell 0" + '"><img src="images/look.png" width="16"></a>'
                 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always help myself with this trick:

Don't set `bVisible` to false cause you will not have the data in the row. It's not rendered at all. Use `sClass` and set `display:none`. This way the column is invisible to the user, but it is still there.

Then you can use `mRender` to show a custom cell template:

```
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      "aTargets": [0],
      "sClass": "hiddenID"
    }, {
      "aTargets": [1],
      "bSearchable": false,
      "bSortable": false,
      "sClass": "center",
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a href=" http://somepage.php?UID=' + full[0] + '">Click me</a>';
      }
    }, {
      "aTargets": [2],
    }, ]
```

Now the data is there, sortable and filterable.

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LvXnHfoHu2OE6rvtc4Of?p=preview) and style.css to understand the concept behind this hack.

Comment: Excellent mainguy.  Thank you very much, I see exactly what you are getting at.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a closer look at `mData` so you can do a callback function and dont have to use the hidden column:

```
// Using mData as a function to provide different information for
// sorting, filtering and display.
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "User_ID",
          "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false
        }
    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": [ 0 ],
      "mData": function ( source, type, val ) {
        if (type === 'set') {
          source.id = val;
          // Store the computed dislay and filter values for efficiency
          source.id_display = val=="" ? "" : '<a href="somepage.php?UID=' + val + '"><img src="images/look.png" width="16"></a>';
          source.id_filter  = val=="" ? "" : val;
          return;
        }
        else if (type === 'display') {
          return source.id_display;
        }
        else if (type === 'filter') {
          return source.id_filter;
        }
        // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
        return source.id;
      }
    } ]
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, DerDu.

The idea was to not have the User_ID column shown at all.

I thought I had to have it in the table in order to get its cell data.
User_ID is a column in my MySql table that I would like to use for the HTML link.

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way to begin with???

Comment: all roads lead to Rome ;-) .. so the question is how will you build the table .. everything on server? only data on server and table at client?, all at client?, json data?.. and so on.. maybe i could answer "the wrong way"-question if you tell me more about what your doing ;-)

Comment: I have a table being generated from DataTables with data from an MySql database table. I am trying to have an icon in the first column of my table that is a link to another page.  I need to pass the User_ID to that page once the icon is clicked.  I do not need the User_ID in the table to be shown.  I have several columns in the table after the icon column, specifically, edit and delete icons.  Based on the User_ID, I need those icons to turn Gray and not be selectable.  I was able to get that working fine when I made the table, but as I have DataTables making the table, I am getting lost.

Comment: So first you did html "by hand" and used the dataTable plugin.. and it works, but now you try to build the table in pure javascript without predefined html table.. correct? .. so how do you "convert/inject" your mysql data to javascript.. ajax request? json encoded string? "write" javascript directly to the page?

Comment: "sAjaxSource": "tf_data.php",

Comment: Well, I say it worked.  I had the edit/delete icon turning gray and not selectable.  However I could not figure out how to get the User_ID into the icon link for the first column.  That's when I went to DataTables generated table.

Comment: hm.. what happens if you use ```"sAjaxSource": "tf_data.php",``` and not ```aoColumns``` with the example above? .. sry i can't get a jsfiddle to work ^^ ... @mainguy solution seems quite acceptable